# AWS RDS stuck changing vpc security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been trying to create a copy of an RDS I have under the same vpc as the old snapshot (but with a new name).

I restored from a snapshot and went into the modify and changed the vpc security group, however the console is stuck with a "removing" and "adding" message.

The vpc it is trying to add is indeed correct, however it is taking forever to change. Doing a bit of research, apparently vpc is supposed to be quick to change, so what gives?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tngbq.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Terraform where changes were not applied directly. See this [GH Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9692).

I was able to fix it using the AWS CLI, the console didn't allow me to apply the changes.

```
aws rds modify-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier ... \
    --db-subnet-group-name ... \
    --vpc-security-group-ids ... \
    --apply-immediately
```

Answer (score 2):

Went back into the modify tab and applied the same changes.

Reading more carefully, I think the reason for the initial issue was I forgot to click "Apply changes immediately" and the change was scheduled for the next maintenance period.

Hope this helps if anyone runs into a similar issue!